# Deploy to another workspace in synapse with CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

Currently I am able to deploy to Synapse via the Azure DevOps portal pipeline that I made with the UI. I am trying to achieve the same result via a yml file but I am encountering the problem `[error]Encountered with exception:Error: No file found with this pattern` and I have the following code:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
        - workspace_publish

pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: Build stage
jobs:

    - job: Deploying

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy ARM Template Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: testsaws
    Contents: '*json'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    #PathtoPublish: ./testsaws
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'ASA_Drop'
  
- task: AzureSynapseWorkspace.synapsecicd-deploy.synapse-deploy.Synapse workspace deployment@1
  displayName: 'Synapse deployment task for workspace: qasaws'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'dataplatform-qa-group-SPN'
    subscriptionId: 'XXX'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'dataplatform-qa-group'
    location: 'West US 2'
    TemplateFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/ASA_Drop/ARM/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
    ParametersFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/ASA_Drop/ARM/TemplateParametersForWorkspaceQA.json'
```

Any help or suggestion in finding the problem is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, print out the contents. I used the following command to print out the content of the current working directory and found out the artifact didn't contain any file.

```
# PowerShell
# Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    #targetType: 'filePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inline
    #filePath: # Required when targetType == FilePath
    #arguments: # Optional
    #script: '# Write your PowerShell commands here.Write-Host Hello World' 
    # Required when targetType == Inline
    #errorActionPreference: 'stop' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #warningPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #informationPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #verbosePreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #debugPreference: 'default' # Optional. Options: default, stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #failOnStderr: false # Optional
    #ignoreLASTEXITCODE: false # Optional
    #pwsh: false # Optional
    #workingDirectory: # Optional
```

Then I changed the following in the yaml file:

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    #PathtoPublish: ./testsaws
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'ASA_Drop'

- task: AzureSynapseWorkspace.synapsecicd-deploy.synapse-deploy.Synapse workspace deployment@1
  displayName: 'Synapse deployment task for workspace: qasaws'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'qa-group-SPN'
    subscriptionId: 'XXX'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'qa-group'
    location: 'West US 2'
    TemplateFile: 'testsaws/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
    ParametersFile: 'testsaws/TemplateParametersForWorkspaceQA.json'
```